# Playbook failing execution due to permission denied

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Here is the inventory content:

```
[osm]
osm_host ansible_port=22 ansible_host=10.20.20.11 ansible_user=ubuntu ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/key/key
```

And here is the playbook content:

```
- hosts: osm
  user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Download the OSM installer
      get_url: url=https://osm-download.etsi.org/ftp/osm-8.0-eight/install_osm.sh dest=/tmp/install_osm.sh
    - name: Execute the OSM installer
      shell: /tmp/install_osm.sh
```

When I run `ansible-playbook -i inventory play.yaml`, I get the following error:

> PLAY [osm]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
> ********************************************************* ok: [osm_host]
>
> TASK [Download the OSM installer]
> ********************************************** ok: [osm_host]
>
> TASK [Execute the OSM installer]
> *********************************************** fatal: [osm_host]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/tmp/install_osm.sh", "delta":
> "0:00:00.001919", "end": "2020-09-04 19:26:46.510381", "msg":
> "non-zero return code", "rc": 126, "start": "2020-09-04
> 19:26:46.508462", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/install_osm.sh:
> Permission denied", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/install_osm.sh:
> Permission denied"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
>
> PLAY RECAP
> ********************************************************************* osm_host                   : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0
> failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

I tried to use `true` and `yes` for the `become` clause, but nothing changed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be sure that the root user has executable permissions on the new OSM download. When you use a **become: yes** without **become_user**, the default user is **root**
So you need to be sure that root user can execute your script.

Try the get_url like that:

```
- hosts: osm
  user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Download the OSM installer
      get_url: 
        url: https://osm-download.etsi.org/ftp/osm-8.0-eight/install_osm.sh 
        dest: /tmp/install_osm.sh
        mode: "0555"
    - name: Execute the OSM installer
      shell: /tmp/install_osm.sh
```

Play with the **mode** param of the **get_url** module.

Comment: Yes. As I am new to Ansible, I just forgot that I should set the file permissions to execute. I was thinking this should be a problem in my Ansible file. =] Thank you. By the way, the OSM script requires a user different from root, so, I removed the `become: yes`. ;)